# What is using all the RAM in this python script?

Tags: python, memory, profiling

I have  very simple python script as follows.  In my use it just counts the number of distinct strings of length 2 in a [text file of DNA](http://wikisend.com/download/877316/test.fa).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Count the number of distinct kmers in a file
import sys
def kmer_count(dna, k):
    total_kmers = len(dna) - k + 1
    # assemble dict of kmer counts
    kmer2count = {}
    for x in range(len(dna)+1-k):
        kmer = dna[x:x+k]
        kmer2count[kmer] = kmer2count.get(kmer, 0) + 1
    return(len(kmer2count))


workfile = "test.fa"
f = open(workfile, 'r')
dna = f.readline()
print "Number of bytes to represent input", sys.getsizeof(dna)
print "Number of items in dict", kmer_count(dna, 2)
```

This prints

```
Number of bytes to represent input 10000037
Number of items in dict 71
```

And yet when I look at the memory usage using

```
/usr/bin/time --format="Size:%MK  Cpu:%P  Elapsed:%e" ./kmer.py
```

I get

```
Size:332776K  Cpu:100%  Elapsed:2.57
```

What is using all the RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `range` in your for loop, which constructs a list containing all the numbers. This is bound to be very big.

In Python 2, loop over `xrange` instead: xrange lazily creates the numbers for the for loop as they are needed.